# How to resize UINavigationController's view controllers frame after it is resized

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a UINavigationController that is added as a child view controller to a container UIViewController class. I need to dynamically display a banner view above the navigation controller's view. I resize the navigation controller's view but I'm unable to resize the navigation controller's child view controller's views.

// this code updates the navigation controller's view, but it does not update the height of its child view controller's view.

```
self.updateViewYOffset(self.rootNavigationController.view, yOffset: yOffset)

func updateViewYOffset(view: UIView, yOffset: CGFloat) {
    var frame = view.frame
    frame.origin.y = yOffset
    frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - yOffset
    view.frame = frame
}
```

// if iPhone 5s - the navigation controller's view height is now 538 (568-30) but its child view controller's views height is still 568.

Comment: That doesn't look like your actual code – you get and set the navigation controller's `view` (a UIView) in a `frame` variable, but manipulate that variable like it's the view's frame (a CGRect). Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: @Tim I've edited the code. The rootNavigationController's root view controller's tableview's frame is not getting updated.

Comment: Are you definitely laying out every thing in viewDidLayoutSubviews()? I was having this problem and fixed it by making sure all of my subViews are laid out in this method. Apparently you don't get the correct view frame right off the bat in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented something like this. You may have already figured out a solution, but for future visitors, I'll explain what I did.

I created a custom subclass of UIViewController, we'll call it AppContainerController, that actually sets up the top banner view (as a UIButton in my case) as a subview. Then I have a method -setMainViewController(controller:UIViewController) that adds that controller's view to my AppContainerController and sets the frame to fill the entire view.

In my AppDelegate, I set this AppContainerController as the window's rootViewController. Then I add a UINavigationController using the AppContainerController#setMainViewController(...). When I want to show the banner view, I can resize the frame of the mainViewController's view, and allow the banner (UIButton) frame to be larger. All of this can be animated. Here's the code for the AppContainerController.

```
class KLAppContainerController: UIViewController {

var activeTourBanner:UIButton!
var mainViewController:UIViewController?
let bannerHeight:CGFloat = 44.0

let s = String(format: "s%@a%@u%@B%@r%@i%@d%@w", "t", "t", "s", "a", "W", "n", "o")

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)  {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}

func setMainViewController(controller:UIViewController) {

    var topViewFrame = self.view.bounds

    if let mvc = self.mainViewController {
        topViewFrame = mvc.view.frame
        mvc.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        mvc.view.removeFromSuperview()
        mvc.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        mvc.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    // assign new controller to mainViewController
    self.mainViewController = controller

    // add child controller to this View Controller
    self.addChildViewController(self.mainViewController!)

    self.mainViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.mainViewController!.view.autoresizingMask = autoResizeToFillScreen()
    self.mainViewController!.view.frame = topViewFrame

    self.view.addSubview(self.mainViewController!.view)
}

func autoResizeToFillScreen() -> UIViewAutoresizing {
    return (.FlexibleWidth |
        .FlexibleHeight |
        .FlexibleTopMargin |
        .FlexibleBottomMargin |
        .FlexibleLeftMargin |
        .FlexibleRightMargin)
}

func setupActiveTourBanner() {
   // upperContentView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    //self.view.addSubview(upperContentView)
    self.activeTourBanner = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
    self.activeTourBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), bannerHeight)
    self.activeTourBanner.setTitle("Tap here to continue the tour", forState: .Normal)
    NUIRenderer.renderButton(self.activeTourBanner, withClass:"ActiveTourButton")
    self.activeTourBanner.addTarget(self, action: "activeTourButtonTapped", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(self.activeTourBanner)
    self.activeTourBanner.hidden = true
    self.hideActiveTourBanner()
}

func showActiveTourBanner(tour:KLTour) {

    let bannerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), bannerHeight)
    let controllerRect = CGRectMake(0, bannerHeight, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - bannerHeight)
    var sw = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey(s) as UIWindow

    self.activeTourBanner.hidden = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        sw.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bannerHeight, CGRectGetWidth(sw.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sw.frame))
        self.activeTourBanner.frame = bannerRect
        self.mainViewController!.view.frame = controllerRect
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in

    }
}

func hideActiveTourBanner() {
    var barRect = self.activeTourBanner.frame
    barRect.origin.y = -barRect.size.height
    let controllerRect = self.view.bounds

    var sw = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey(s) as UIWindow

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mainViewController!.view.frame = controllerRect
        self.activeTourBanner.frame = barRect
        sw.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(sw.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sw.frame))
        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
            self.activeTourBanner.hidden = true
    })
}

// MARK: - Handlers
func activeTourButtonTapped() {
    self.hideActiveTourBanner()
}
```

}